# Price of in-app purchases shown on screen(with currency)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want the buttons that you have to tap to buy something to show the price of that.

For example: "5 coins €0,99"

But if I create a UIlabel with exactly that text, Americans will also see the price in € instead of usd.

Now how can I set the price where it adjust to the currency the user lives in?
I saw it on some games so I am convinced that this is possible.

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get locale currency price for in-app purchases in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453910/how-to-get-locale-currency-price-for-in-app-purchases-in-ios)

Answer (score 21):

If purchases are done via Apple App Store (using StoreKit framework) you need to get price + currency from SKProduct object (prices will vary).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/

**Update**

1. you need to perform request to load available products

```c
var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: “product_id_on_itunes_connect”);
var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
productsRequest.delegate = self;
productsRequest.start();
```

2. Request [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKProductsRequestDelegate/productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:) will return [SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/).

```c
func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    println("got the request from Apple")
    var validProducts = response.products
    if !validProducts.isEmpty {
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            println(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else {
            println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        println("nothing")
    }
}
```

3. SKProduct contains all needed information to display localized price, but I suggest to create SKProduct category that formats price + currency to user current locale

```c
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {

    func localizedPrice() -> String {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        return formatter.stringFromNumber(self.price)!
    }

}
```

Information taken from [here](https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/swift-storekit-in-app-purchases) and [here](http://bendodson.com/weblog/2014/12/10/skproduct-localized-price-in-swift/).

#### Swift 4

```c
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {
    var localizedPrice: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = priceLocale
        return formatter.string(from: price)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to to localize (internationalize) your interface and texts.

In order to do that you'll have look how to do it for :

- Your storyboard (you'll still handle one, but translate the texts you want in an inside file)
- Inside your code. Trough `NSLocalizedString` for example : http://goo.gl/jwQ5Po (Apple), http://goo.gl/S1dCUW (NSHipster), ...