# How to fetch InApp Purchase Product Prices in Local currency in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, currency-formatting

I am implementing InApp Purchase Products in AppStoreConnect where we get to choose the price in Dollars($). Let's say I have created a Product with the Price of **$0.99** which is equivalent to **£0.89**. Now I want to display the equivalent price of United Kingdom in my App. But unfortunately All I am able to achieve is to get **£0.99** from different solutions that provides locale price based on the settings. But this is wrong as I want to ideally display the actual price in GBP which is only 0.89 and not 0.99.

Any help in resolving this would be very helpful.

P.S:- I have tried solutions from [How to get locale currency price for in-app purchases in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453910/how-to-get-locale-currency-price-for-in-app-purchases-in-ios?rq=1) but none seem to work properly.

Comment: The price that is displayed when you use the price locale depends n the country of the store account not the device locale since it is the store account that determines how the user is charged.. To display a price in GBP you will need to use a sandbox user that is set up for the UK.

Comment: Are you doing this in the simulator (with StoreKit config in Xcode) or with a physical device with StoreKit configured to pull from apple connect? The pricing would only reflect actual if you're pulling from StoreKit Apple Connect.

Comment: I am fetching in a physical device and not on a Simulator.